# Notation question: $\ll$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I was perusing http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HighlyCompositeNumber.html and saw the following at the end: Nicholas proved that there exists a constant $c_2>0$ such that $Q(x) \ll (\ln x)^{c_2}$.   What does the $\ll$ mean in this context? (fyi, $Q(x)$ is the number of highly composite numbers less than or equal to $x$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbols $\ll$ and $\gg$ denote "asymptotically very much less than" and "asymptotically very much greater than," respectively.

Comment: Hmm,   looking in the wikipedia, then it's equivalent to $Q(x)\in O((\ln x)^{c_2})$,  right?

Comment: @Alan It is related...  Notice that $f \in O(f)$ for all functions $f$.  But, $f\not \ll f$.  The use of the symbols $\ll$ imply that one is *much* larger than the other, rather than simply asymptotically bounded.  Also, the $\ll$ symbol doesn't have to refer to asymptotic performance; one could say $3 \ll 10^{100}$.

Comment: @Alan The times where I have seen it used, it is not properly defined what exactly the "asymptotically very much" means.

Comment: Hmm.  I get the concept of very much smaller,  just not exactly seeing a formal meaning.  Oh well, taking a course in asymptotics next semester, hopefully I'll get a better grasp then.

Comment: Its open to interpretation as I understand, but a general rule of thumb I would suggest is at least different by 3 orders of magnitude.  I think you would agree that $5 \ll 8000$.  Depending on how strict or specific you want to be you may want that $f(x)\ll g(x) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < M$ for some constant $M\in [0,1)$.  To be at least 3 orders of magnitude larger as I suggested, $M$ would be $.001$

Comment: @JMoravitz check, that helps solidify it.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, $\ll$ and $\lll$ can refer to much less than, or very much less than respectively.

There do exist other uses for the symbols as well.  In particular, in measure theory (seemingly unrelated to your specific example), for two measures $\lambda$ and $\mu$, you have that $\lambda \ll \mu$ (i.e., $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$) if for all sets $\mu (E) = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda (E) = 0$